# Aceitar somente numéricos no input

Tags: python, string

```
nota = -1
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:
    nota = int(input("Informe a nota entre 0 e 10: "))
    if nota < 0 or nota > 10:
        print("Valor inválido")
```

Eu preciso incluir nesse código validação para, se caso o usuário digitar string (a,b,c,d,e,f...) ou caractere especial, ele mostre erro e solicite novamente o inteiro.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basta você tratar a exceção que é disparada pelo `int` quando a conversão falhar:

```
while True:
    try:
        nota = int(input("Informe a nota entre 0 e 10: "))
        if not 0 <= nota <= 10:
            raise ValueError("Nota fora do range permitido")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Valor inválido:", e)
    else:
        break

print(nota)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MVTg/0)</sup>

O `while True` garante que a leitura será efetuada até que o `break` seja executado; o `try/except` captura a exceção disparada pelo `int`, que é um `ValueError`, exibindo a mensagem de erro; se a exceção não é disparada, o bloco `else` é executado, parando o laço.

Comment: Anderson você é o cara, muito obrigado resolveu instantaneamente.

Answer (score 3):

Então, há outras maneiras de fazer. Uma delas é usar o input como string e reconhcer o tipo do valor lido. Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
nota = -1
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:
    nota = input("Informe a nota entre 0 e 10: ")
    if nota.isdigit():
        if nota < 0 or nota > 10:
            print("Valor inválido")
    else:
        print("Não parece ser um número")
```

[Aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) tem uma referencia para isdigit.

Para versões do python anteriores a 3, pode ser necessario usar `raw_input` no lugar de `input`.

Answer (score 1):

```
nota = -1
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:
    try:
        nota = int(input("Informe a nota entre 0 e 10: "))
        print("A nota foi:", nota)
        break
    except:
        print("Valor inválido")
        continue
```

O comando *continue* faz com que volte para o início do loop.

Comment: Nesse caso, se a exceção é disparada, o valor de `nota` não é alterado, então o *loop* irá continuar mesmo sem o `continue`.  Só faria sentido ali se houvesse mais código após o bloco try/except.

Comment: E talvez se fazer `while not 0 < nota < 10` fique mais legível que `while nota < 0 or nota > 10`, mas isso está mais para opinião mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma interessante de se resolver esta questão, com **Python 3.8 ou superior** é utilizando os conceitos de **[Assignment Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)**, abordados pela **[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)**.

Com esses conceitos poderemos reduzir bastante a quantidade de linhas no código. Desta forma o código pode ficar:

```
while not (nota := input(f'Nota entre "0" e "10": ')).isdigit() or (nota := int(nota)) < 0 or nota > 10:
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

print(nota)
```

Observe que o bloco **while** verifica **três** situações:

1. Verifica se a expressão atribuída à variável **nota** não é um dígito;
2. Verifica se a expressão atribuída à variável **nota** e convertida em **inteiro** é menor que **0**;
3. Verifica se a expressão atribuída à variável **nota** e convertida em **inteiro** é maior que **10**.

Caso uma das três verificações do bloco **while** seja **True** receberemos a mensagem: `Valor INVÁLIDO!` e seremos novamente solicitado uma nota entre "0" e "10".

Agora, caso as três verificações do bloco **while** sejam **False**, o laço de repetição será encerrado, sendo exibido o valor da nota digitada.

Answer (score -3):

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class Aplicacao:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root

        self.tela()
        self.entradas()
        self.inputs()
        
        root.mainloop()

    def tela(self):
        self.root.title("Validação")
        self.root.geometry("100x100")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    def inputs(self):

        self.inComplemento = Entry(self.root,validate="key",validatecommand=self.valor)
        self.inComplemento.place(relx=0.100, rely=0.1,
                                 relwidth=0.70, relheight=0.30)
        self.inComplemento.focus_set()

    def entradas(self):
        self.valor = (self.root.register(self.valida),"%P")

    def valida(self, text):
        if text == "":
            return True
        try:
            value = int(text)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        return 0 <= value < 1000000
```