# Impedir que o usuário quebre o programa

Tags: python-3.x, input

Gostaria que o código não quebrasse caso o usuário colocasse uma letra no lugar de um numero na variável: chute. Esse trecho de código funciona muito bem se o usuário adicionar numero, mas se adicionar uma letra, já era! O código quebra.

Desde já muito obrigado a todos

```
chute = input("Escolha quantos chutes você pode dar! Escolha um numero entre 1 e 7")

if (int(chute) < 1 ):
    print("XXX")
    jogar()
elif (int(chute) > 7):
    print("YYY")
    jogar()
else:
    print("Ok, você tem {} chutes" .format(chute))
```

Comment: Adicionei uma outra resposta na pergunta [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244764/aceitar-somente-num%c3%a9ricos-no-input)