# Dá pra fazer com menos variáveis?

Tags: python

Construir um programa solicita que o usuário digite inteiros positivos, finalizado por 0, e cuja saída seja: "sim X", sem as aspas, se a sequência contiver X valores positivos e formar uma sequência crescente; caso contrário imprima "nao X".

```
a = int(input("Digite o primeiro valor da sequencia: "))
b = int(input("Digite o segundo valor da sequencia: "))

i=1

if a == 0:
    print("nao ", 0)
if a>0 and b == 0:
    print("sim ", 1)

while a>0 and b>0:
    i=2
    c = int(input("Digite outro valor da sequencia: "))
    if c>b:
        i = i + 1
    if c<b:
        i = i + 1
    a = int(input("Digite algum outro valor da sequencia: "))
    b = a
    c = b
    a = c

if a == 0 and c>b:
    print("sim ", i)
if a == 0 and c<b:
    print("nao ", i)
if c == 0 and c>b:
    print("sim ", i)
if c==0 and b<c:
    print("nao ", i)
```

Comment: Aparentemente não, porém dá para fazer melhor, mas o código está confuso e não sabemos o objetivo, o que dificulta falar algo apropriado.

Comment: Então, o objetivo é "um programa que solicita que o usuário digite inteiros positivos, finalizado por 0, e cuja saída seja: "sim X", sem as aspas, se a sequência contiver X valores naturais e formar uma sequência crescente; caso contrário imprima "nao X".

Answer (score 1):

Para ler a sequência, basta você modificar um pouco a resposta que publiquei em:

[Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/5878)

```
numeros = []

while True:
    try:
        numero = int(input("Informe um número inteiro positivo: "))
        if numero < 0:
            raise ValueError("O número deve ser inteiro positivo ou zero.")
        elif numero == 0:
            break
        else:
            numeros.append(numero)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Valor inválido:", e)
```

E, para verificar se a lista de números está em ordem crescente:

```
ordenado = numeros == sorted(numeros)
```

Finalmente, para obter o tamanho da lista, a função nativa `len`:

```
tamanho = len(numeros)
```

Assim ficando:

```
numeros = []

while True:
    try:
        numero = int(input("Informe um número inteiro positivo: "))
        if numero < 0:
            raise ValueError("O número deve ser inteiro positivo ou zero.")
        elif numero == 0:
            break
        else:
            numeros.append(numero)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Valor inválido:", e)

ordenado = numeros == sorted(numeros)
tamanho = len(numeros)

print(f'sim {tamanho}' if ordenado else f'não {tamanho}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/JealousShadowyPlans)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ola, não sei se você já aprendeu sobre listas em python mas vai um código bem simples
E não entendi o porque você quer que imprima 'sim, X' e 'nao, X'  mas inseri ai.
a atribuí à variável sequencia o '[]' assim dizendo que ela sera uma lista, e fiz um loop simples sempre que for True ele continuara se o a for igual a '0' ele da um break no loop caso contrario ele adiciona à lista com o metodo .append() a variável a. No final ele imprime a lista. sorted(X) == ordena o X(uma lista) de forma crescente.
Espero ter ajudado.

```
sequencia = []
x = 0
while True:
    a = int(input('Digite o valor'))
    if a == 0:
        print('não', x)
        break
    else:
        print('sim', x)
        sequencia.append(a)
    x += 1




print(sorted(sequencia))
```