# bloco Try e except

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necessito realizar este programa:

Reescrever seu programa de pagamento usando try e except para
que o programa trate entradas não numérica amigavelmente imprimindo uma
mensagem e saindo do programa. A seguir mostra duas execucões do programa:

```
Digite as Horas: 20
Digite a Taxa: nove
Erro, por favor, informe entrada numérica
Digite as Horas: quarenta
Erro, por favor, informe entrada numérica
```

O
meu código é o seguinte:

```
numero_horas=input("Digite o numero de horas:")
valor_hora=input("Digite o valor hora:")
print("Erro, digite numeros")
valor_total=int(numero_horas*valor_hora)
print("Valor total", valor_total)
try:
    valor=int(valor_total)
    print("Valor de Pagamento é:", valor)
except:
    print("Inicie programa novamente")
```

Só que dá este erro :

```
valor_total=int(numero_horas*valor_hora)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

como poderei resolver este problema?

Comment: Você está multiplicando duas strings; precisa converter para int antes.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244764/aceitar-somente-num%c3%a9ricos-no-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `input` retorna string. Assim sendo, antes de fazer contas com os retornos você deve convertê-los.

Além disso, você fala que o exemplo é de duas execuções do programa, assim, entende-se que ao receber um entrada não numérica o programa, além de apresentar a mensagem de erro, é interrompido (`sys.exit`).

Como o mesmo tratamento é dado para dois inputs, é melhor criar uma função (`int_or_exit`) para evitar repetição de código.

```
import sys


def int_or_exit(int_string):
    try:
        int_valor = int(int_string)
    except ValueError:
        print("Erro, por favor, informe entrada numérica")
        sys.exit(1)
    return int_valor


input_numero_horas = input("Digite as Horas: ")
numero_horas = int_or_exit(input_numero_horas)

input_valor_hora = input("Digite a Taxa: ")
valor_hora = int_or_exit(input_valor_hora)

valor_total = numero_horas * valor_hora
print("Valor de Pagamento é:", valor_total)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, resolveu o que queria,valeu

Answer (score 1):

Sergio o problema é que voce está setando as variáveis como **INT** depois da multiplicação, esse erro quer dizer que você está multiplicando **strings**, por isso o problema.

tente desse forma:

```
numero_horas=input("Digite o numero de horas:")
valor_hora=input("Digite o valor hora:")
try:
    #print("Erro, digite numeros")
    valor_total=int(numero_horas)*int(valor_hora)
    print("Valor total", valor_total)
    valor=int(valor_total)
    print("Valor de Pagamento é:", valor)
except ValueError:
    print("Inicie programa novamente")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, resolveu o que queria,valeu