# Erro na função def

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como poderei calcular valor do salário com numero de horas acima de 40 como definido no if, tento correr com 41 horas mas dá-me este erro

```
salario = float(40*valor_hora+(h_excd*(1.5*valor_hora)))#valor salario com horas extras

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
def calcular_pagamento(qtd_horas, valor_hora): # função calcular o pagamento de salário
    horas = float(qtd_horas) #converte string para float e é a variável de horas que pode ser float
    valorhora = float(valor_hora) #converte string para float e é a variavel do valor hora que pode ser float
    if horas <= 40:
        salario=horas*valorhora#valor salario sem horas extras
    else:
        h_excd = float(horas - 40) #calculo horas extras
        salario = float(40*valor_hora+(h_excd*(1.5*valor_hora))) #valor salario com horas extras
    return salario # retorna o valor de salário

n_horas= input('Digite numero de horas: ') # string numero de horas
n_valor_hora=input('Digite valor hora: ') #string valor hora
total_salario = calcular_pagamento(n_horas,n_valor_hora) # vai buscar o valor de retorno da função 
print('O valor do salário é:',total_salario,"€") # dá o valor de salário
```

Comment: É exatamente o mesmo problema da [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308389/5878): você está tentando multiplicar coisas que não são números. Provavelmente é a variável `valor_hora`, visto que você converte para *float*, mas salva em `valorhora`, sendo que nem utiliza esta variável. Preste mais atenção ao escrever o código, por favor.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [bloco Try e except](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308389/bloco-try-e-except)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve alterar a linha:

```
salario = float(40*valor_hora+(h_excd*(1.5*valor_hora)))
```

para:

```
salario = float(40*valorhora+(h_excd*(1.5*valorhora)))
```

Você converteu a variável `valor_hora(string)` para `float` e chamou de `valorhora` só esqueceu de usar