# Sorteio Dentro de Uma String em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou fazendo um programa em Python, cujo o enunciado é o seguinte:

**Crie uma função que recebe uma string e transforma alguns dos caracteres em maiúsculos e outros em minúsculos.**

Eu preciso que o usuário informe a quantidade de sorteios que ele deseja fazer, por exemplo: Se ele quiser sortear 3 números, o programa sorteará 3 números entre 0 e len(string), depois o programa verifica se a string na posição sorteada é maiúscula ou minuscula, se for maiúscula transforma em minuscula e se for minuscula transforma em maiúscula...
Eu Fiz esse programa em C e queria fazer em python também, mas não estou conseguindo, fiz até aqui: (mas está dando erro)

```
from random import randint
frase = str(input("Digite a String: "))
while True:
    qntd_sorteio = int(input("Quantos números deseja sortear? "))
    if qntd_sorteio >= 1:
        break
    else:
        print("O número precisa ser um número real...")
pos = 0
while qntd_sorteio > 0:
    pos = randint(0, len(frase))
    if frase[pos].isupper():
       frase[pos].lower()
    elif frase[pos].islower():
       frase[pos].upper()
    qntd_sorteio -= 1
print(frase)
```

Não sei qual o erro, não sei como transformar, se alguém puder me ajudar...

Comment: Não sabe qual é o erro? Ele não apareceu quando você tentou executar o código?

Comment: Aparece "IndentationError: unexpected indent" Na linha do "if frase[pos].isupper():"

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/

Comment: Isso é erro de indentação. Dentro do seu `while` há um `if` indentado de forma errada. Em Python é trivial que você formate corretamente todas as linhas de código.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Isso ele já fez no código dele, não entendi qual o objetivo de citar esse link...

Comment: Ah sim, desculpa, isso eu tinha reparado porém não tinha arrumado aqui, mas o problema continua, eu faço os sorteios e tudo mais e quando vou printar a string, ela printa sem alterações nenhuma

Comment: O meu unico problema, é que as alterações não estão sendo feitas, elas entram nos Ifs e Elses, mas quando eu faço a atribuição, para alterar para maiusculo ou minusculo, elas não alteram

Comment: Erro não é de sintaxe @AndersonCarlosWoss https://repl.it/repls/KnottyNanoPacket

Comment: Só preciso saber como eu transformo, por exemplo: "Q", em "q", porque a atribuição que eu estou fazendo não está correta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O principal problema da resposta é que utilizou os métodos `lower` e `upper` como se fossem modificadores do objeto. Em Python uma *string* é imutável e, por definição, não pode ser modificada. Nesse caso, os métodos `lower` e `upper` **retornam** uma nova *string* com a caixa alterada.

Outros pontos são:

1. Não precisa fazer `str(input(...))`; o retorno da função `input` sempre será uma *string*.
2. Acredito que não fará sentido sortear os valores desta forma, pois haverá a possibilidade de sortear um mesmo número mais de uma vez gerando uma saída inesperada; se eu informasse 4 caracteres e ele sorteasse duas vezes o mesmo valor eu teria apenas 2 caracteres modificados.

Outra forma de resolver seria:

```
from random import sample

frase = input('Informe a frase: ')
quantidade = int(input('Informe a quantidade: '))
posições = sample(range(len(frase)), quantidade)

resultado = ''

for posição, letra in enumerate(frase):
  if posição in posições:
    letra = letra.swapcase()
  resultado += letra

print(resultado)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LightsalmonPrimeGravity)</sup>

- A expressão `sample(range(len(frase)), quantidade)` irá gerar uma sequência de N números entre 0 e `len(frase)-1`, inclusive, de forma aleatória e sem repetição;
- Com o auxílio de `enumerate` é percorrido cada letra da frase junto com a sua posição; quando a posição da letra for uma posição sorteada é invetido a caixa da mesma; a letra é concatenada em uma nova string de resultado.
- Com a função `swapcase` é invertida a caixa da letra; isto é, se ela for minúscula será retornada como maiúscula e vice-versa.

Comment: Seu ponto 2 está correto, no exercicio ele também pediu que os numeros sorteados não fossem iguais, dai eu faria alguma coisa do tipo "if sorteio not in lista", dai faria o resto do código, não coloquei essa parte do enunciado aqui no stack pois ia ficar algo muito grande pra ser explicado, mas voce tem razão

Comment: @BrennoCarvalho A função [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) recebe dois parâmetros: uma população (sequência de valores) e uma quantidade k. O retorno será uma nova sequência de k valores da população tomados de forma aleatória e sem repetição.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui entender certinho e com um código bem menor do que eu estava fazendo antes :)

Comment: @BrennoCarvalho Só veja que eu não tratei a entrada em `quantidade` na resposta, pois como você já fez isso na pergunta assumi que já sabia fazer. Se quiser saber mais, já comentei sobre isso em [Aceitar somente numéricos no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244764/5878)

Comment: sim sim, eu percebi, mas isso é um pouco indiferente, aqui meu código eu já fiz também, mas mto obrigado mesmo :D

Answer (score 1):

```py
# encoding: utf-8
from random import Random
frase = raw_input("Digite a String: ")
while True:
  try:
    qntd_sorteio = int(raw_input("Quantos números deseja sortear? "))
  except ValueError:
    print "Deve ser um número inteiro!"
  if qntd_sorteio < 0 or qntd_sorteio > len(frase):
    print "Deve ser entre 0 e", len(frase)
  else:
    break

posicoes = Random().sample(xrange(len(frase)), qntd_sorteio)

lista_letras = list(frase)

for i in posicoes:
  lista_letras[i] = lista_letras[i].upper() if lista_letras[i].islower() else lista_letras[i].lower()

print ''.join(lista_letras)
```